# MOV playback not working using UIImagePickerController with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have read similar threads regarding movie playback in a MPMoviePlayerController after selecting a video using UIImagePickerController including:

[MPMoviePlayerController do not play movie picked from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455299/mpmovieplayercontroller-do-not-play-movie-picked-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

- Releasing the picker and/or the moviePlayer on playback complete or a combination of the two does not resolve my issue.

[Problem playing mov file in MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493860/problem-playing-mov-file-in-mpmovieplayercontroller)

- My movie is recorded via the iPhone real-time and will not have any codec issues - its a standard MOV

My code is below - and believe me, I have tried every permutation I can fathom with this code. I have also tried to use MPMoviePlayerViewController, presenting it modally using the UIViewController MediaPlayer Additions - presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if ( currentMediaType == kMediaTypeVideo ) {
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]];
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:current_player_view.bounds];
        [current_player_view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    }

}
```

I have also tried adjusting how I provide the movie path to the MPMoviePlayerController - I recognize I can access the path like so:

```
[[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"] path];
```

...and therefore can provide the NSURL with this code instead:

```
NSString *chosenMoviePath = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"] path];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:chosenMoviePath]];
```

However this does not resolve the issue either. There really shouldn't be any crazy extreme trick to recording a video and immediately playing said video in the movie player. Seriously. Its all on the device. Any help is *extremely* appreciated. I've spent much to much time on this already.

Thanks in advance!

J

Comment: Now with the release of iOS 5, the issue resolved itself which leads me to believe this an iOS 4 bug. In addition, I now see a different issue on iOS 4 devices, the video does appear to load for playback for a split second, but disappears before you can do anything with it. I have ensured the view is on top of the stack and all other subviews are behind the player but this does not resolve the issue. The fact that I could only start to see the playback after upgrading everything else to iOS 5 outside of the device is an indication that this isn't just a simple code resolution on my end.

Answer (score 4):

To resolve - I finally discovered if I don't animate the dismissModalViewController for the UIImagePickerController, then the playback displays for the video. The best I can conclude is that the animated dismissal has a delay which can cause other code to not execute immediately. So below works:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    if ( currentMediaType == kMediaTypeVideo ) {
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]];
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:current_player_view.bounds];
        [current_player_view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg, i would never think about this. Thanks for solution!!